# All but Five Three Colorable

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, reductions, colorings

An NP Problem Named All But Five Three Colorable(AB53C) is defined as follows :- Input : Connected Graph G(V,E) The Connected Graph is AB53C, iff the Given Graph is 3-Colorable by leaving UPTO 5 Vertices Uncolored.

Question:- The Problem is in NP. Show the reduction from 3-Colorable Problem.

The Proposed Solution is :-

Find Permutation of All Subsets where |V'| = |V| - 5. Basically these subsets will have 5 vertices less than the original set. Remove all edges from V' to V. All such subsets are found out and then passed through the 3-Color. If we get YES on any one of these Subgraphs, then we have a AB53C.

I want someone disprove my method OR show that the reduction is non-polynomial. Otherwise, my proposal is correct.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Can you suggest a reduction? I have a proposal, but I dont want to contaminate the readers thought by my proposal.

Comment: I suggested a reduction in my answer. But generally on this site we appreciate people showing effort on solving their questions on their own. For example, if you have a proposed reduction but can't prove that it works, you could share it with us.

Comment: Your proposed reduction is not a many-one reduction, though it's a valid oracle reduction. Since it's not a many-one reduction, it can't be used to prove NP-hardness. Also, your reduction goes in the wrong way. You need to show how to solve 3-colorability using AB53C rather than the other way around.

Comment: (Polynomial time) many-one reductions are the ones appearing in the definition of NP-hardness. If you look at any textbook or lecture notes (or even Wikipedia) on NP-hardness, I'm sure you'll find a definition and examples.

Comment: Why do you doubt your approach? Do you have a *specific* question, i.e. one distinct from "please grade my hand-in"?

Comment: @Raphael: I want a CRITIQUE and good discussion on my Answer from people interested in Algorithms and Computational Complexity.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for your inputs. I still cannot understand why my answer is not Many-One Reduction.

Comment: @user10584 You have to go over all subsets of size $|V|-5$ and pass all of them separately to the 3-colorability oracle. In contrast, in a many-one reduction you only pass on one instance. In any case, as I mention earlier, this is reduction in the wrong direction. We already know that every problem in NP can be many-one reduced to 3-colorability, since 3-colorability is NP-hard.

Comment: @user10584 That's fine, but simply not what SE is suitable for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Add a clique on 8 vertices to the graph.

Comment: Clique is a Complete Graph. It will consider cases for Complete Subgraphs only. WE have a connected Graph.

Comment: Right, you'll have to connect the clique to the rest of the graph in a smart way. You'll also have to connect the various connected components of the original graph in a smart way.